# Menu disappears with binding

Tags: android

I want to show a custom menu on my app. But when as soon as I bind my model to the view the menu disappears. At the end of the post I attached two Pictures.

This is my activity code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agency_detail)
    val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    val agencyDao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnection(this), AgencyModel::class.java)
    val agency = agencyDao.findLast { item -> item.id == intent.getIntExtra(AgencyDetailActivity.ARG_ITEM_ID, -1) }

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityAgencyDetailBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_agency_detail)
    binding.agency = agency
}
```

When I remove the binding lines it works properly, but with the binding it doesn't work.

This is how it should look

[image: how it should look]

This is how it Looks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was tricky but it is pretty simple. You have to assign the toolbar after you bind the data. This is the corrected Code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val agencyDao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnection(this), AgencyModel::class.java)
    val agency = agencyDao.findLast { item -> item.id == intent.getIntExtra(AgencyDetailActivity.ARG_ITEM_ID, -1) }

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityAgencyDetailBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_agency_detail)
    binding.agency = agency

    val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```